Salesforce as Idp: Why Certificate tag is being shared in SAML response from Salesforce?
I've configured my Salesforce instance as IdP and able to validate that end-to-end flow of SSO is working fine with target application (SP).
I've captured SAML response from Salesforce to target app (SP). This saml response carries Certificate tag. This is the same certificate value as the one I used on ConnectedApp.
I want to understand why this certificate value is being shared in SAML response, which can easy be seen/tracked by middle parties?


This is perfectly normal. Certificate is a container for public key, relying parties use the public key to verify the signature attached to the SAML response. Take a look at SAML technical overview for better understanding of how this works.

Thanks @identigral. Gone through samples given in the "SAML technical overview", could not locate tag X509Certiicate anywhere. I thought, since public key is already shared with SP during the initial configuration, why it is again being shared in the SAML assertion? Anyways, while going through https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-an-x-509-certificate/ , it became clear to me that this X509Certificate value is a public-key which will be used for encrypting values/data, for decrypting it back to original form someone would need private-key.

You're right, SAML Tech Summary doesn't go into this detail. The <KeyInfo> element is defined in XML Signature spec, SAML includes XML Signature by reference - the core SAML spec talks about this in section 5.4. While SAML supports encryption (see section 6 in spec above), the example you're citing has nothing to do with encryption.
